# Entity Core save multilevel entity and last entity is master data

Tags: entity-framework-core

Parent table.

```
public class Indent 
{   
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<IndentTable> IndentTableCollection { get; 
     set; }

    public virtual int StoreID { get; set; } 
}
```

Child Table contains master due to need of dropdown , drop down data comes from master

```
public class IndentTable 
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public virtual string ContractorName { get; set; }
    public virtual MasterRegister.MasterRegister MasterRegister { get; set; 
     }
    public virtual long IndentID { get; set; }
}
```

Master Table already available before creating Indent or IndentTable

```
public class MasterRegister 
{       
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public virtual string MaterialNameWithDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public virtual string MaterialUnit { get; set; }

}
```

Master register is already created a newly created Indent need to add Indent and IndentTable only but entity freamework also try to add MasterRegister.

I need to create new Indent and IndentTable with reference of master , but Master remain intact.

Any suggestion.

Comment: If Master is already present in database then either you need to set the FK property in IndentTable to Master's ID or fetch Master from database and assign it to navigation property in IndentTable.

Comment: Entity framework add indent, IndentTable with master register id as foreign key , one extra thing done by entity is he try to add new masterregister entry but addition is not desirable no action should be taken on master register.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Smit I got the ans by searchiing releated content on google.

```
foreach (var indentTable in indent.IndentTableCollection)
        {

            MAS.Core.Domain.Store.MasterRegister.MasterRegister masterregister = indentTable.MasterRegister;
            _context.Entry(masterregister).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
```

With this code not change to masterregister and all work fine.